# как решить проблему в чтении кириллицы в названии исходного кода python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Учу сейчас `python`, и не могу понять, по какой причине питон не может прочитать некоторые русские символы, например "М" и "П" (вне зависимости от регистра), причем большинство других символов он читает. При попытке скомпилировать файл с названием, где встречаются символы указанные ранее, появляется ошибка:
`can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

У меня есть догадки, что это возможно проблема среды, в которой я пишу (vscode) с дополнительными расширениями (`ms-python.python`, `tht13.python`), но я не уверен в этом

Comment: Только что создал файл "мп.py" и из него прочитал файл "мп.txt". Всё работает без ошибок (`Python 3.7.3 IDLE`)

Comment: @Стас,  Очень странно... Сейчас тоже создал файл мп.py, и он у меня тоже заработал, но проверив другие файлы где использовал букву п, и он у меня ту же ошибку выводит что раньше

Comment: Вот сейчас сделал файл "основы ооп.py", "основы oop.py" и "ооп.py", первый не сработал, а второй и третий сработал. Очень странно

Comment: Просто в терминале на убунте все работает - любой из представленных вариантов. А операционка - винда? Как запускается скрипт, какой-нибудь кнопкой в vs code? Не может же быть, чтобы прям дело было именно в двух символах и ничего больше.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не знаю в чем проблема, но у меня получилось решить ее уж слижком костыльно.

При открытии полного репозитория, где хранятся файлы питона, сразу открывается в vscode страничка (по крайней мере у меня так), в которой предлагают выбрать папку (рис.1), в которой необходимо работать. Выбираем "open a folder", после чего выбираем нужную папку, где хранятся скрипты, после чего запускаем компиляцию, и магическим (для меня) образом, все работает (рис.3)

[image: страница, которая автоматически открывается]рис.1

[image: Вывод ошибки]рис.2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]рис.3